# Angular2 + Jasmine - Unable to test router configuration

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular2 + Jasmine - Unable to test router configuration

I'm running into a weird issue while running a jasmine test for my router.
This is a simple Angular2 app with bunch of route configs to route request to 2 components.
In my Jasmine test suite for testing the router, when I provide my application component for 'ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT', it does not seem to accept it.
Seems like something in failing in this test suite during initialization.
But I do not see any error in the browser console. 
Trying out debug breakpoints in the application files didnt fetch any clue. 
There are no error on the server as well. I'm using angular v2.0.0-beta.15.
The Jasmine test report simply ignores [or does not show] that test suite. 
The application runs fine in runtime. The issue is in the jasmine test suite.
Rest of the test suites for this application seem to be work fine.

Any ideas to debug this issue is much appreciated!

This is my AppComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-emp', styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'], template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,EmpProfServ]
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/employees', name: 'Employees',component: EmpProfCmp,useAsDefault: true},
  { path: '/employees/:id', name: 'EmpProfDetail', component: EmpProfDetailCmp},
  { path: '/**',redirectTo: ['Employees'] }
])
export class AppComponent {}
```

This is my route.spec test file:

```
import {describe,it,expect,inject,beforeEach,beforeEachProviders} from 'angular2/testing';
import {Router, Location, ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT} from 'angular2/router';
import {RouteRegistry} from 'angular2/src/router/route_registry';
import {SpyLocation} from 'angular2/src/mock/location_mock';
import {RootRouter} from 'angular2/src/router/router';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

describe('Test Application Routes',()=>{
    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        RouteRegistry,
        provide(Location, {useClass: SpyLocation}),
        provide(Router, {useClass: RootRouter}),
        provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: AppComponent })
    ]);
    ....
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you call `setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
    TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);`?

Comment: No, I don't have any such call to explicitly set any test providers. - Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/969b55326c8281a9e4a3d850ee7e368a276c9d13/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta2-2016-01-28

Comment: Thanks for the link Günter. It's still the same behavior though. No errors, the specs are simply not executed.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8083 might provide some info. I haven'r tried router testing myself yet.